# ArrayTypeMismatch Exception in Session

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, session, exception, authorization

I have a website written in ASP.NET MVC. There is some custom authorization logic and the following attribute added.

```
public sealed class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
```

Right in the override of AuthorizeCore method I try to access Session and:

1. HttpContext.Current.Session != null
2. HttpContext.Current.Session.IsNewSession == false
3. But HttpContext.Current.Session.Keys throws an ArrayTypeMismatch exception. Also HttpContext.Current.Session["SomeKey"] throws the same exception. As a result I cannot get values from the session.

More information:
Mode: SQL server

```
<sessionState allowCustomSqlDatabase="true" cookieless="UseCookies" mode="SQLServer" sqlConnectionString="Server=.;Database=ASPState;integrated security=true;" timeout="120" sqlCommandTimeout="240" />
```

Stack Trace:

at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.ParseArrayMember(ParseRecord pr)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.ParseMember(ParseRecord pr)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Parse(ParseRecord pr)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary._*BinaryParser.ReadMemberReference()
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.*_BinaryParser.Run()
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Deserialize(HeaderHandler handler, __BinaryParser serParser, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
   at System.Web.Util.AltSerialization.ReadValueFromStream(BinaryReader reader)
   at System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateItemCollection.ReadValueFromStreamWithAssert()
   at System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateItemCollection.DeserializeItem(String name, Boolean check)
   at System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateItemCollection.get_Item(String name)
   at System.Web.SessionState.HttpSessionStateContainer.get_Item(String name)
   at System.Web.SessionState.HttpSessionState.get_Item(String name)
   at {mynamespace}.SessionHelper.get_UserSessionContext() in d:{mypath}\SessionHelper.cs:line 41
   at {mynamespace}.CustomAuthorizeAttribute.AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext) in d:{mypath}\CustomAuthorizeAttribute.cs:line 50
   at System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute.OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAuthorizationFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c_*DisplayClass25.b*_1e(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState)

Can anybody explain me why this error occurs, how can I troubleshoot it and possible ways to fix that?

Comment: Have you stored anything non-trivial in session? What session provider are you using? In-memory? Sql server? Etc. If something persistent like sql server: have have built recently? Are all server bodes using the same version of the software? (I.e. is it possible that the persisted data does not match the current build)

Comment: Also: what is the stack trace?

Comment: See updated post, we use SqlServer mode and this error I get on my local environment. I get this error after restarting the application, when in that AuthorizeCore method. It used to work correctly when session only called from the controllers, now I have this strange error after added session logic to AuthorizeCore

Comment: @lhor does it work from a different browser? (i.e. a clean session) I think you've corrupted that particular session...

Comment: That's correct, when I tried in FireFox first time it went smoothly without any error. Then in Visual Studio I clicked Restart (Ctrl+Shift+F5) - site restarted and the same error occurred then. Is it possible somehow to detect what exactly causes corruption of the session?

Comment: what are you storing? Any dynamically generated classes? Maybe from Entity Framework or NHibernate, or anything else that isn't **simple flat POCOs**? Frankly, I would say that the best approach for stability is: only store strings or blobs; anything like XmlSerializer, Json.NET or protobuf-net can help with that. Storing non-trivial objects in session state is asking for trouble.

Comment: Yes, some instances of Entity Framework generated classes are stored in Session. I agree with your point, but unfortunately it can be too much too refactor, if even possible, to avoid such.

Comment: if you want it to work, you're going to need to change something...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like the all-too-common problem of a type-based serializer (`BinaryFormatter`, `NetDataContractSerializer`, etc) being used with incompatible types between builds. In the general case, this kinda-sorta works enough that it *usually* allows you to use the same data between builds (since you don't usually change the types involved very much), but: there's a big problem when dynamic type generation - which is used extensively in tools like Entity Framework and NHibernate. Essentially, because they subclass at runtime it is virtually guaranteed that you will never be able to deserialize between rebuilds, or possibly even app-restarts and between different nodes in a cluster.

Two pieces of guidance here:

- never ever store your standard domain entities in session (or cache): have a dedicated DTO (i.e. a simple type that represents the data you want to store) and store that. If possible, make this type immutable (in particular to avoid issues with same-object vs clone, which changes between provider)
- if possible, take control of the serialization such that it is not dependent on type definitions: "contract based" serializers like XmlSerializer, Json.NET or protobuf-net all allow you to work with CLOB or BLOB data at the session (or cache) layer, with pain-free serialization/deserialization even if you move types between assemblies and rename them