# Sharing 2 Applications: Session State Deserialization Error for ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net, session, iis, session-state, application-pool

I'm hosting two applications under one website on IIS. The main application creates a session state when the user logs in. I am able to share the session between the two applications, but when I try to access the specific session variable I get a deserialization error seen below. On my second application, I load the dll (in Global.asax during start up) that it claims is missing. I even confirm that it has been loaded before accessing the session and it still throws an error. The library that's loaded is from the same directory and has the same exact assembly string that it's complaining about.

Perhaps it's loading it to a different domain of the application? Does anybody know why it's still not working? Any suggestions would be great.

(Unable to find binary)
[image]

(Confirmed that the DLL is properly loaded upon startup for the second app)
[image]

```
>     [SerializationException: Unable to find assembly 'Jenzabar.Portal.Framework, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=null'.]
>        System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryAssemblyInfo.GetAssembly()
> +4491385
>        System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.GetType(BinaryAssemblyInfo
> assemblyInfo, String name) +14472268
>        System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectMap..ctor(String
> objectName, String[] memberNames, BinaryTypeEnum[] binaryTypeEnumA,
> Object[] typeInformationA, Int32[] memberAssemIds, ObjectReader
> objectReader, Int32 objectId, BinaryAssemblyInfo assemblyInfo,
> SizedArray assemIdToAssemblyTable) +179
>        System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.ReadObjectWithMapTyped(BinaryObjectWithMapTyped
> record) +278
>        System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.Run()
> +914
>        System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Deserialize(HeaderHandler
> handler, __BinaryParser serParser, Boolean fCheck, Boolean
> isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage) +169
>        System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream
> serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, Boolean
> isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage) +288
>        System.Web.Util.AltSerialization.ReadValueFromStream(BinaryReader
> reader) +1064
>        System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateItemCollection.ReadValueFromStreamWithAssert()
> +68
>        System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateItemCollection.DeserializeItem(String
> name, Boolean check) +256
>        System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateItemCollection.get_Item(String
> name) +29
>        ASP._Page_Views_Account_Login_cshtml.Execute() in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\auxtest\Views\Account\Login.cshtml:25
>        System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +252
>        System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +148
>        System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +86
>        System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext
> pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +107
>        System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +375
>        System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1
> filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext,
> ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +88
>        System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1
> filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext,
> ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +775
>        System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext
> controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +81
>        System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_1.<BeginInvokeAction>b__5(IAsyncResult
> asyncResult) +188
>        System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult
> asyncResult) +38
>        System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginExecuteCore>b__152_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +26
>        System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
> asyncResult) +68
>        System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +52
>        System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
> asyncResult) +39
>        System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +38
>        System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginProcessRequest>b__20_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +40
>        System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
> asyncResult) +68
>        System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +38
>        System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
> +602
>        System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +195
>        System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +128
```

Comment: According to the error message, I suggest you could firstly check the file in the bin directory is the right version. Normally, this is not an IIS problem as much as it is an application problem.

Comment: @BrandoZhang the file is already there in the path. if it were a file issue, it would complain about the path. i've already confirmed this.

Comment: What version of IIS are you using? What server version and .Net version?

Comment: @jkw4703 application pool is running on 4.5, windows server 2016, iis is 10.0.14393

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a dependency issue, yes the file is there, but maybe some other file it depends on is not there. The error message could be a bit misleading

Comment: im thinking so too... the main application loads a lot of libraries

Answer (score 0):

This is a issue with type-based serializer, please refer to this post here
[ArrayTypeMismatch Exception in Session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20439855/arraytypemismatch-exception-in-session)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30491449)